# problem during uploading avi or mpeg files in <form> tag

Tags: forms, input

when i try to upload two files in the form, it doesn't happen!!!
here is my code

```
<input type="file" name="video" />

<input type="file" name="picture" />

<input type="submit"  class="input" value="Save" />
```

but when i post only one file, that's ok!!!
can somebody help me, pleaseee;)

Comment: Need much more code to help you with your situation. The form here is fine. What's happening server-side? Plus, what is your question? Only one file is being uploaded or if you just choose one file, the form is still being submitted? If it's the latter, that's normal - you need some validation (either client- or server-side) to make sure a file is chosen for both inputs.

Comment: You must add to the question the server code that you are using because the HTML is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that this question has not that much details, I'll assume that this might be your problem.

Make sure your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as attribute and method must be `POST`

e.g.

```
<form name="fileUploadForm" action="/toMyAction" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <input type="file" name="video" />
  <input type="file" name="picture" />
  <input type="submit"  class="input" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: hmmm, i've done it already:(((
maybe problem in my local server!!! i tried it on local server!!!

Comment: What's the exact problem you're having? Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: The the server is a problem. Because I've used multiple file upload like this one and has worked beautifully.